# Get Value From ms-access and addition all values Vb.Net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I have my DataBase ms-access Contain Table 'Client' and this table contain : (ClientName, ClientPhone, ClientAddress, ClientCredit, ClientDes)__ok! Im want to addition all values of ClientCredit in my software vb.net . Im use this code and its work but i its give me a wrong value !!

```vb
Dim credit As Double = 0    
Try
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata( _
          "SELECT ClientName, ClientPhone, ClientAddress, ClientCredit, ClientDes FROM Client;")
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        credit = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString + credit
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
FlatTextBox1.Text = credit
```

this code give me result : 400 but the real result is 415.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the index i in the loop. Modify code to be Rows(i) not Rows(0)

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        //credit = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString + credit                   
        // credit is double, why ToString 
        credit = Convert.ToDuble(dt.Rows(i)(3)) + credit          
    Next
```

Other Solution:

You can avoid loop (remove for ..next)  and use Compute method of the DataTable:

```
     credit = dt.Compute("Sum(ClientCredit)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your summation line:

```
credit = dt.Rows(0)(3).ToString + credit
```

should read

```
credit += TryCast(dt.Rows(i)(3), Double)
```